# When using git difftool --dir-diff I would like the modification dates to match to original files / repo

Tags: git, git-difftool

When I use `git difftool --dir-diff` the files are copied to temporary folders and in my diff tool the dates are the time the files were copied.

I'd like the files to have the dates from the working folder / repo.

Is it possible and if so how?

Using Windows 10 and cmd.exe but would consider alternatives to cmd.exe if that makes it possible.

Comment: Git itself won't do that (ever), but you could write your own program that uses the commit dates to set the dates on the checked-out files. Unfortunately, I suspect you'll be reproducing a lot of what `git difftool` does as there's no easy way to insert the "change dates" operation: you could set your program as the tool but it won't know which commit got checked out, and therefore can't fish the date out of that commit.